Deactivating "Seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy” as close reason
The close reason "Seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy" causes confusion and doesn't seem to have too many fans. Oftentimes questions closed with this reason could have been closed for a different reason as they tend to be too basic, too unclear or too broad. 
On the other hand, some questions could be closed for this reason but we as a community like these questions and would want them closed.
Therefore, I propose to remove the option and close questions when necessary using one of the other reasons.
Decision
It has been two weeks and no arguments have been brought forward to keep the reason. Without counting downvotes, the vote is 4 in favour and 1 not. Therefore I'm deactivating the reason.

I see two 3 upvotes and 1 downvote. Both are fine but please share your reasoning!

I think it should be removed.  Developing trading strategies is part of quant finance nowadays.  Like your post says, if the question is too basic or shows no effort, etc. we can close it for those reasons.

The reason can not be removed but it can be deactivated, so changed title to reflect that.

Please remove this as a close reason, it's useless and confusing for the reasons given in the linked discussion and here.

Please keep it, it's a good close reason for the following questions:
